# getBoundingClientRect is empty in mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a site with angular functionality. I've tracked a bug down to the getBoundingClientRect method. It's properties are empty on mobile devices (the app works fine on laptops, etc....

This code:

```
var message = JSON.stringify(element.getBoundingClientRect());
alert(message);
```

sends the following alert on my MacBook:

{"top":164,"right":601,"bottom":468,"left":328,"width":273,"height":304}

and on my iPad:

{}

Why, and is there a fix, or should I start rewriting the JS?

More of the code:

Element stored in var:

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll(selector)[0];
```

Event added:

```
element.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
            getMouseCoordinates(e, element);
    });
```

Event:

```
function getMouseCoordinates(e, element) {
var x = e.clientX - element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y = e.clientY - element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
var message = JSON.stringify(element.getBoundingClientRect());
        alert(message);
    var  shiftX = x - mouseX; ** code was stopping here
```

I've discovered, further, that the ClientRect Object has properties before the Event Listener was assigned (so the same bit of "var message = " code posts a full "{ 'top': ... }" object in mobile browsers outside of the event listener handler, but not in that function).

Comment: Cannot reproduce using device emulation set to `iPad` at chromium

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the code independent of the full application, when I can. My friends and colleagues have been able to reproduce the bug in mobile browsers on Android and Google phones, and a Kindle. I've only been able to check alerts on my devices, running from localhost.

Until then, not sure why that bit of code works for you. :(

Comment: Is element dynamic ? Can describe _"full application"_ ? , _"running from localhost"_ ? What is `element` ?

Comment: The element is dynamic. It's an html canvas, with a photo. There is a cropping UI overlaid, and the cropping window doesn't work on mobile devices. I tracked the bug down to a line of code that performs a mathematical operator on getBoundingClientRect().left, that value being null. The Rect object is not null.

The full application is a website. I'm new to the team, and not sure whether I should post the site here, until it's done.

Running form localhost: I cloned the repository, and am running the clone from a node server on my computer. URL is <My I.P.>:port, on my iPad, and in iOSSimulator

Comment: Is it possible that `.getBoundingClientRect()` is called before `element` exists in document ?

Comment: Nope. Element would be null, and I'm pretty sure the element.get... would stop the script, before the alert.

Comment: Can post portion of `html` , `js` where `element` is defined , `.getBoundingClientRect()` and `alert` is called ?

Comment: _“There is a cropping UI overlaid”_ – and how does that happen? Is the element positioned, fixed or absolute? Maybe something that the mobile device’s browser does not support? Or is it maybe positioned differently on mobile, do the respective styles get overwritten/reset somehow, by a media query? I think without a full example, this is impossible to debug. Create a [mcve] please.

Comment: Then maybe it isn't? I'm not here to have you all do my debugging work for me, and I can rewrite the code, myself. The element is defined in another file, and I COULD post that, and the html, etc..., but that's not really necessary, and I feel a waste of our time, as the answer could be anywhere up the script and DOM trees. I'm just wondering whether anybody might know why the exact same code behaves uniformly among mobile browsers (all platforms, all browsers), but differently than it does on lap and desktops (again, all platforms, all browsers).

Comment: @dylanthelion The issue is `JSON.stringify(element.getBoundingClientRect())` will return `"{}"` even where properties are defined; see solution at post below

Comment: @guest271314: not true (see my original post). The alert that shows on my Macbook (exact same page/line of code) shows : {"top":164,"right":601,"bottom":468,"left":328,"width":273,"height":304}

Comment: @dylanthelion jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cvo5jr6n/

Comment: I'm getting the alert with the full ClientRect obj in your fiddle, as well. Is that what you were expecting? Because that doesn't answer my mobile question (though I appreciate the effort). Also, the getBoundingClientRect() DOES seem to work on the element, after further experimenting. It just doesn't work in the event listener callback.

Comment: Here, first `alert()` returns `{}` here

Comment: Weird, I saw full objects in both. First alert : {"top":8,"right":617,"bottom":8,"left":8,"width":609,"height":0}

Maybe the gods are angry with us?

Comment: _"Because that doesn't answer my mobile question"_ Tried using approach described at Answer below at "mobile" device ? Returned result described at Question , that is , `{}` . That is only way , here, could reproduce result of `{}` at `alert` . _" It just doesn't work in the event listener callback."_ Can describe "doesn't work" ?

Comment: I see! Sorry, I was checking the fiddle on my laptop. I'm still unclear as to why the fiddle behaves differently on the mobile device?

Comment: So, in more detail: the code var message = JSON.stringify(element.getBoundingClientRect());
alert(message); works in the angular module on instantiation, it works everywhere in normal browsers, and does NOT work, only in getMouseCoordinates, called by the event listener. And by "works", I mean the alert is {"top":164,"right":601,"bottom":468,"left":328,"width":273,"height":304} You can see the same difference in your fiddle, if you check out the first alert from a mobile browser, and then a regular browser. Same code, two different results.

Comment: @guest271314: UPDATE: Your fiddle works in the iOS simulator with the most recent version of iOS (9.2). My code does not. And your code does NOT work in 8.4 (which I had on my iPad). Again, "work" indicating that the alert in question comes back "{"top":...}", and not "{}".

Comment: @dylanthelion Is solution to suggest to users to update to `iOS` version that returns expected results ?

Comment: Just updated. My code still doesn't work, but yours does. :P My current best guess is that mobile touch events interfere with JS mouse events. The fiddle may have to do with the older version of iOS. I spent several hours researching this today, and older (before 8) versions of iOS had issues with the getBoundignClientRect() method. Occam wouldn't approve of that answer, though...

Comment: Haha. Sorry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor Also, a friend I trust says that mobile device don't register some mouse events. I'm going to play around with touch events and his suggestions, see if I can get the cropper to work, and TOTALLY TAKE THE CREDIT. :P Unless someone asks.

Answer (score 2):

GOT IT! A friend figured this out, for the most part. Mobile devices don't register mouse events, only touch events, so the code was actually blowing up at the var x = e.clientX - element.getBoundingClientRect().left line. Touch events don't have clientX properties; they have TouchLists whose members have clientX properties Why this left the element.getBoundingClientRect(); an empty object, I'm still not sure of, but the following code works as expected. The isMobile var is set to true, if a mobile device is detected.

```
var touchEvent = (isMobile ? e.changedTouches[0] : e);
        console.log("Mobile: " + isMobile);
        console.log("Touch event: " + touchEvent);

var x = touchEvent.clientX - element.getBoundingClientRect().left,
        y = touchEvent.clientY - element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var message = JSON.stringify(element.getBoundingClientRect());
        alert("bounding rect: " + message);
```

Comment: @mtackes gets the credit for finding the original problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating object , adding properties , values from `.getBoundingClientRect()` to object , then calling `JSON.stringify()` on created object

```
var props =  element.getBoundingClientRect();
var obj = {};
for (var prop in props) {
  obj[prop] = props[prop]
};

alert(JSON.stringify(obj))
```