# Find out how much of the screen is overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm developing and app that works with .pdf files and it's meant to be used on mobile. I need to find out the height and width of and element that is overflowing from the screen as the pdf is being panned through in order to work with coordinates.

[image: Example of something I would have to work with]

Now the question. How can I find out the width and height of the area that is being overflown on either side of the screen (can happen on both sides)?

Answer (score 0):

put this in you css file.

```
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #0f0 !important;
  outline: solid #f00 1px !important;
}
```

it will outline all the element in you code .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you could get the width of the element and then compare 100vw - theWidthOfElement.

If you want to work with coordinates then just window scrollLeft to get the x coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

`element.getBoundingClientRect()` returns an object with properties that include `.width` and `.height`.

These are the width and heigh of an element, and continue off-screen (so, in your case, will be bigger than the viewport dimensions).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

You might also find useful the `.left`, `.right`, `.top`, and `.bottom` properties of `.getBoundingClientRect()`. These, again, extend beyond the screen, returning negative values for left and top, and numbers larger than the viewport for right and bottom.

Often, the element (your pdf, or its container), is defined by a click event, but mobile devices instead rely on `touchEvent`s (and errors in applying them appear to interfer with  `.getBoundingClientRect()` so be careful. (see: [getBoundingClientRect is empty in mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967750/getboundingclientrect-is-empty-in-mobile)).

I could make a demo snippet here but I'm not on a mobile device to test and it might confuse users of other devices. The MDN page on `.getBoundingClientRect()` should get you going.

Comment: I have added an example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-microservice-trqkqz?file=/app.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

When you toggle mobile view you can see what I mean. I need to know how many pixels of pdf cannot be seen on the screen when moving around. using .getBoundingClientRect() will always return same values.

Comment: yes, you have to collect the touch coordinate and do some subtractions using the touch coordinate, screen width, and pdf left/top/bottom/right - pretty basic stuff.

Comment: I did some testing and found out the following: the solution you have suggested works, but only when I was using a div. I'm using a canvas element to render my pdf (pdf.js requires a canvas to render pdf) and for some reason this that is not working.

Comment: I'll have a think, if you can look insidethe pdf.js library, you might be able to glean some information about how it positions the pdf inside the canvas and what coordinates it works on. I haven't used pdf.js but will have a look when I get time.

Comment: I had a look at an example renderd in pdf.js (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html), diging into the inspector a little, it seems the pdf is ultimately converted to html elements. Key to the display is a container division with id="viewer" inside which is a collection of child divs with class="page".

Comment: If you load your page, open browser developer tools and make a reference to the parent division (`const pages=document.getElement.ById("viewer").children`) pages should now contain an html collection of one or more page divs. Then type `pages[0].getgetBoundingClientRect()` and console should list the data for that page. (you can move the page about and repeat) There may be left/right/top/properties off the page and this might give you the key to extracting them. No idea how you do this on a mobile device but it's all I can suggest at present.